# create new div-tags depending on elements in XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Im creating a sticky note function that will(soon) let me write data into the textfield and save it in a xml file.

For now I have some information inside an xml file that i want to output in the notes,

The problem is that i would like each element be in different notes.
for now its reading the entire xml file into one note.

This is the xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<notes>
  <note>
    <text>Hello, Yes this is dog!</text>
  </note>
<note>
    <text>Hello,this is cat!</text>
  </note>
</notes>
```

/*This should be on two notes*/

and this is my Jquery and Ajax function

```
function corporateData() {
        var note = '<div class="note">';
        note += '<div class ="note-drag">' + '</div>';
        note += '<textarea>' + '</textarea>';
        note += '<div class="note-close">' + '</div>';

        $("#wrapper").append(note);



    $.ajax({
        url: "write.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {

            $(data).find("note").each(function() {
                var info = $(this).find("text").text();
                $("textarea").append(info);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $("textarea").children().remove();
            $("textarea").append("<li>Error</li>");
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function corporateData() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "write.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function (data) {

            $(data).find("note").each(function () {
                var info = $(this).find("text").text();

                var note = '<div class="note">';
                note += '<div class ="note-drag">' + '</div>';
                note += '<textarea>' + '</textarea>';
                note += '<div class="note-close">' + '</div>';

                $(note).find("textarea").text(info);

                $("#wrapper").append(note);
            });
        },
        error : function () {
            $("textarea").children().remove();
            $("textarea").append("<li>Error</li>");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, had a typo. But for now i don't get any information from the xml.